# QuotedStr replacing Double Quote In Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I need to make a comma separated string which would have multiple string values and each of these value should be in single quote.

When I am using QuotedStr, it is quoting with double-quote,instead of single.

I even tried using single-quote but still it is having same issue.

I tried googling but didn't get any resulting info.

Any other ways to make it ?

Regards.

Vishal

Comment: No, it wraps the string by single quotes. What you might see are two consequent single quotes.

Comment: How could I just insert a single quote, ex. 'abc', 'xyz', 'pqr'. I either get 'abc,xyz,pqr' or ''abc'',''xyz'',''pqr''. What should I do to get the desired result?

Comment: It sounds like you are concatenating that string by youself; if so, then just concatenate all of its parts, and finally wrap the result by `QuotedStr`.

Comment: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Comment: Wow! I posted my answer literally in the last minute.

Answer (score 2):

QuotedStr adds a *single* quotation mark at the beginning and at the end of the string, passed as argument.
What may be misleading is how the debugger shows strings.

For example, the following code

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a, b, c, r: string;
begin
  a := 'A';
  b := 'B';
  c := 'C';
  r := QuotedStr(a) + ',' +
       QuotedStr(b) + ',' +
       QuotedStr(c);
  Label2.Caption := r;  // breakpoint here
end;
```

with a break point on the last line shows this in the `Local Variables` pane:

[image]

but the actual label caption looks like this:

[image]

The debugger encloses strings in single quotes for display, and because your strings already contains single quotes, it looks like there would be double quotes.

---

The code that you posted in a comment ...

```
procedure TForm9.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var MyString : String;
begin
  //#44
  MyString := QuotedStr('String1');
  MyString := MyString + ',' + QuotedStr('String2');
  ShowMessage(MyString);
end;
```

... produces this result:

[image]

and if the message is expanded with showing the length, like this:

```
  ShowMessage(MyString + '  Length: ' + IntToStr(Length(MyString)));
```

... it produces this:

[image]

Single quotes, length is as expected.

Comment: WHile debugging, when I click on the variable and press Ctrl+F7 to see actual value in the variable, it still shows with two single quotes.

Comment: @VishalTiwari As I said, that is the way the debugger shows strings, whether it is in the 'Evaluate/Modify' window, 'Local/Variables* pane or where ever.

Comment: But my query component returns record count zero after sql execution.

Comment: @VishalTiwari Then it seems you have been focusing on the wrong issue for the whole week since you asked. I suggest you post a new question which includes the code where you are creating the query. It is simply not possible to guide you if you don't provide enough facts about your issue.

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyString : String;
begin
  //#44
  MyString := QuotedStr('String1');
  MyString := MyString + ',' + QuotedStr('String2');
  ShowMessage(MyString);
end;

Comment: I get MyString value as '''String1'',''String2'''. single quote two times. Replace String is also not helpful.

Comment: Display is the different issue. It should give me two records if I pass this string to my parametrized SQL.

Comment: @VishalTiwari I updated my answer with results of your code.

Comment: As I said, display message won't display won't two single quotes. it is in the sql execution of query component it still takes two single quotes.

Comment: @VishalTiwari So, then ask a new question regarding the SQL query. The error is not with QuotedStr.

Comment: I think, you are not getting that this is a issue of two single quotes. There is no issue from sql, as the two single quotes are getting passed, so it is oblivious that SQL would fail.

Comment: @VishalTiwari There are many things I'm not getting, sure! One is that I don't get double single quotes with QuotedStr.

Comment: Okay. Let me try myself.